# what is replacements of some attributes of android-manifest file that has been removed in level 6?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I checked the difference report of [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com).

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

So I found that some attributes of manifest file from android package have been removed, for example:

```
String ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION  
String ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER    
String AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS     
String BRICK     
String CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA   
String DEVICE_POWER  
String FORCE_BACK    
String GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO     
String HARDWARE_TEST     
String INJECT_EVENTS     
String INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW    
String MANAGE_ACCOUNTS   
String MANAGE_APP_TOKENS
```

now I'm going to know that is there any  replacement for each one?  or there is no need to verify  these type of permissions after then.Please help me about that.